# Karate: test count using failsafe + parallel runner

Tags: karate

I'm writing some integration tests using failsafe.

There are two features like this:

```
Feature: example feature 1
  Scenario:
    Given url 'http://httpbin.org/'
    When method get
    Then status 200
```

My "suite" is:

```
public class ApiIT {
  @Test
  public void testParallel(){
    Results results = Runner.path("classpath:.").tags("~@ignore").parallel(5);
    assertEquals(results.getErrorMessages(), 0, results.getFailCount());
  }
}
```

When I run integration tests using mvn (`mvn clean install`) I get:

```
Karate version: 0.9.6.RC4
======================================================
elapsed:   1.41 | threads:    5 | thread time: 1.39 
features:     2 | ignored:    0 | efficiency: 0.20
scenarios:    2 | passed:     2 | failed: 0
======================================================

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.558 sec - in ApiIT
```

Is there any way to count the real tests so I can get this in the logs:

```
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.558 sec - in ApiIT
```

I uploaded an example project here: https://github.com/italktothewind/test-count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. Ignore the last line, that is JUnit because you have 1 `@Test` annotation. What matters here is the Karate output. JUnit makes it simpler to call Karate. But if it bothers you so much, call the `Runner` using a Java main method.

Comment: To be honest, I like more the previous approach using @RunWith(Karate.class) because it was more integrated with JUnit and there was no test code at all, but I'm using this because I need the Cucumber report. It would be great to have the report feature using the @RunWith(Karate.class) approach :)

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if the default folder for reports has to be named "surefire-reports" because you can also call your tests using Failsafe plugin (like in many Karate projects). Maybe it could be called just "karate-reports".

Comment: @italktothewind - the documentation explains in detail WHY we have 2 different approaches. I guess you haven't read it. answer to second question is because it is a common CI (e.g. Jenkins default) so it makes it easier for teams.

Comment: I read it, is because you want to make the parallel feature independent from JUnit and other test frameworks. But I still think that Cucumber reporting should be something orthogonal to parallelization.

Comment: @italktothewind so run parallel with 1 thread and you get the JSON. what's the problem ?

Comment: The problem is that the Runner approach for parallelization does not have the same integration with JUnit like the @RunWith(Karate.class) approach. The Runner approach is more like running a test framework inside other test framework, it does not reuse any feature from JUnit. I need to code by myself even the fail condition (assertEquals). As I said, I would like not to change from @RunWith to Runner because of the Cucumber reports as the don't have nothing to do with the fact that tests are being run in parallel or in a sequential way.

Comment: @italktothewind so you didn't understand the docs at all. the parallel runner should NOT be integrated with JUnit because it will slow things down. Karate really doesn't need JUnit. it is there only for people like you who "feel better" when you see the green bar and the UI with the "tree" of tests so you can navigate to code etc. when running in CI you rely on the HTML reports.

Comment: JUnit integration is really important as it is the most popular test framework for Java and there are a LOT of libraries and IDE plugins that work with it. And I just wonder why I can't have Cucumber reports using the @RunWith(Karate.class) approach, they are not related to parallelization at all.

Comment: BTW I think that your framework is great, I just want to help as a final user that brings real use cases.

Comment: @italktothewind and it is my job to focus on the feature-requests that make sense and to ignore the noisy users (remember you are the ONLY one who has complained about this ;) - we do support JUnit - but ONLY as a test-runner in DEV mode, nothing more. and here is an answer you may not have expected, we have a new built-in report that replaces (and improves upon) the Cucumber report that you get even with the JUnit runner: https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/1237797240686522369 - have you seen it yet ?

Comment: Looks nice! It has evolved a lot since the previous version. I like that you focus on scenarios and tags and that there are no useless useless steps aggregations like other reporting tools.

Comment: @italktothewind great I think we have a common understanding now. so this report is unified for the parallel and JUnit runners. you save a step, you don't have to write code to generate HTML. and we expect users to use this instead of the Cucumber reports in the long term. we will even drop the Cucumber reports in the stand-alone JAR if you are familiar with it. of course we will continue to emit the Cucumber JSON for those who want "compatibility"